# 301 Website redirection issue

Tags: asp-classic

I have just added 301 redirection to the website. When i am hitting the URL from chrome it goes to the new URL, but if i hit the same old URL again it opens the old website. Looks like its loading the website from cache. I made some changes in the page to verify that & those did not appear. So this is for sure that page is never hit.
If server is hit, then 301 works and new page gets loaded.. otherwise old page is being server from the cache.

How can i find out which cache is it being served from ? any DNS cache or server cache? I just want that new page to be served all the time.

Comment: try to set cache expiration to -1 on your page. See what happen. And by the way is this classic ASP or NET app?

Comment: @AllBlond Good question as people tend to use tag [tag:asp] thinking it's [tag:asp.net] when it is in fact a synonym for [tag:asp-classic].

Comment: Thanks Guys.. Its classic ASP classic application. I have done both redirections.. Response.Redirect as well from IIS properties.

Comment: here is a good way to clear your problem: [link]http://www.w3schools.com/asp/prop_expires.asp[/link]. Since it is classic ASP it will show you how to be sure that page never get cached or cached for a limited time. You also need to make sure that box "Cache ISAPI extensions" unchecked on your application configuration or app pool configuration depend on what version of IIS you are using.